# Alignment in custom winforms label control

Tags: c#, winforms, label, text-alignment

I used this answer: [Alpha in ForeColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636065/alpha-in-forecolor)
to create a custom label element that allowed fading through ARGB unlike the default label.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyLabel : Label {
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    Rectangle rc = this.ClientRectangle;
    StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    using (var br = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor)) {
      e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, br, rc, fmt);
    }
  }
}
```

I was curious how I would implement TextAlign into this class allowing the text contents to be aligned correctly.

Comment: Set the properties in `StringFormat' for that : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.alignment(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Aybe's comment, I worked out I needed to add the Alignment to the StringFormat var fmt like this:

```
fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
```

Making the entire class look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyLabel : Label {
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    Rectangle rc = this.ClientRectangle;
    StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        using (var br = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, br, rc, fmt);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding `e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);` somewhere (probably at the beginning of the method). I had some weird text display issues using your solution without it